# Seeking a formula (e.g. $x\cos(t)+y\sin(t)$) that points to each specific binary number on the constellation graph

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me with a method to find a formula that points to each specific binary number on the constellation graph (shown)?

[image]

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the term "constellation graph", but I found the Wikipedia ["constellation diagram" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_diagram). The numbers in your figure don't match the "16-QAM" figure in that entry. I guess that's allowed, but it raises the question: What's the logic behind your arrangement of the values? Knowing this would seem necessary to devising an appropriate formula. Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3682519/edit) to include any details or clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the table:
$$\begin{array}{r|r|rr|rr}
\text{Binary} & \text{Decimal} & x & y & r & \varphi \\
\hline
0000 &  0 &  1 &  1 & \sqrt{2} & 45^o \\
0001 &  1 & -1 & -1 & \sqrt{2} & -135^o \\
0010 &  2 & -1 &  3 & \sqrt{10} & 108.435^o \\
0011 &  3 &  1 & -3 & \sqrt{10} & -71.565^o \\
0100 &  4 &  1 &  3 & \sqrt{10} & 71.565^o \\
0101 &  5 & -1 &  1 & \sqrt{2} & 135^o \\
0110 &  6 &  1 & -1 & \sqrt{2} & -45^o \\
0111 &  7 & -3 &  1 & \sqrt{10} & 161.565^o \\
1000 &  8 & -3 & -1 & \sqrt{10} & -161.565^o \\
1001 &  9 & -3 & -3 & \sqrt{18} & -135^o \\
1010 & 10 & -1 & -3 & \sqrt{10} & -108.435^o \\
1011 & 11 & -3 &  3 & \sqrt{18} & 135^o \\
1100 & 12 &  3 &  3 & \sqrt{18} & 45^o \\
1101 & 13 &  3 & -1 & \sqrt{10} & -18.435^o \\
1110 & 14 &  3 &  1 & \sqrt{10} & 18.435^o \\
1111 & 15 &  3 & -3 & \sqrt{18} & -45^o \\
\end{array}$$
One obvious choice is a 15th degree polynomial in $x$, and another in $y$.  Let $k$ be the number on the constellation graph.  Then,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x(k) &= \displaystyle + \frac{-241}{12108096000} k^{15} + \frac{9769}{4358914560} k^{14} + \frac{-356407}{3113510400} k^{13} + \frac{420227}{119750400} k^{12} \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{-86203963}{1197504000} k^{11} + \frac{63073}{60480} k^{10} + \frac{-61940597}{5644800} k^9 + \frac{6470796127}{76204800} k^8 \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{-26331862201}{54432000} k^7 + \frac{1750393243}{870912} k^6 + \frac{-713779229567}{119750400} k^5 + \frac{242500171267}{19958400} k^4 \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{-72416553177929}{4540536000} k^3 + \frac{12031330511}{1009008} k^2 + \frac{-169717846}{45045} k + 1 \\
y(k) &= \displaystyle \frac{487}{54486432000} k^{15} + \frac{-6191}{6227020800} k^{14} + \frac{311803}{6227020800} k^{13} + \frac{-241133}{159667200} k^{12} \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{24268757}{798336000} k^{11} + \frac{-3751567}{8709120} k^{10} + \frac{1346192921}{304819200} k^9 + \frac{-206200241}{6220800} k^8 \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{39658975859}{217728000} k^7 + \frac{-146201149}{201600} k^6 + \frac{3402243827}{1663200} k^5 + \frac{-117759948359}{29937600} k^4 \\
~ &+ \displaystyle \frac{21936249638959}{4540536000} k^3 + \frac{-18155135321}{5405400} k^2 + \frac{25369349}{25740} k + 1 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
The divisors have mostly common factors, so you can find the greatest common divisor and use a single division per coordinate.  Or you can use floating-point values, and use the approximate values, then round the result to nearest integer.

In a real world application, that function is useless.  For encoding, 16-entry ($4 \times 4$) look-up table is used:
$$\begin{array}{rrrrrl}
p[0 .. 15] = [ & ( 1,  1), & (-1, -1), & (-1,  3), & ( 1, -3), & ~ \\
           ~   & ( 1,  3), & (-1,  1), & ( 1, -1), & (-3,  1), & ~ \\
           ~   & (-3, -1), & (-3, -3), & (-1, -3), & (-3,  3), & ~ \\
           ~   & ( 3,  3), & ( 3, -1), & ( 3,  1), & ( 3, -3)~ & ] \\
\end{array}$$

A decoder essentially calculates 
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
s_{0}  &= (x + 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 \\
s_{1}  &= (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 \\
s_{2}  &= (x - 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 \\
s_{3}  &= (x + 1)^2 + (y - 3)^2 \\
s_{4}  &= (x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 \\
s_{5}  &= (x - 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 \\
s_{6}  &= (x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 \\
s_{7}  &= (x - 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2 \\
s_{8}  &= (x - 3)^2 + (y - 1)^2 \\
s_{9}  &= (x - 3)^2 + (y - 3)^2 \\
s_{10} &= (x - 1)^2 + (y - 3)^2 \\
s_{11} &= (x - 3)^2 + (y + 3)^2 \\
s_{12} &= (x + 3)^2 + (y + 3)^2 \\
s_{13} &= (x + 3)^2 + (y - 1)^2 \\
s_{14} &= (x + 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2 \\
s_{15} &= (x + 3)^2 + (y - 3)^2 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
and uses symbol $i$ for which $s_i = \min(s)$, i.e. the symbol that is closest to $(x, y)$.  Except that there are many ways to do *essentially* the above, without having to do 8 pre-multiplications ($(x-3)^2$, $(x-1)^2$, $(x+1)^2$, $(x+3)^2$, $(y-3)^2$, $(y-1)^2$, $(y+1)^2$, and $(y+3)^2$) and 16 additions.

The trivial way, it turns out, is that if you clamp $-3 \le x \le +3$ and $-3 \le y \le +3$, and you have a look-up table $q[0..15] = [ 9, 10, 3, 15, 8, 1, 6, 13, 7, 5, 0, 14, 11, 2, 4, 12 ]$, then the symbol $b$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ is
$$b(x, y) = \displaystyle q \Biggr [ \left\lfloor \frac{x + 3}{2} \right\rceil + 4 \left\lfloor \frac{y + 3}{2} \right\rceil \Biggr ]$$
where $\lfloor ~ \rceil$ denote rounding towards nearest integer.  This is because the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of this constellation diagram (i.e., the regions around each symbol) is a regular rectangular grid with $x$ and $y$ spacing $2$.